# Specification name

Tags: nusmv, ctl

I want to know how to attribute names to properties inside SMV file.

I have done this but only from the terminal (see the following code)

```
NuSMV > add_property  -c -p "AG !(Object1.state = ready &  AX Object2.state = running)" -n "first"        
NuSMV > check_property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/userman/v26/nusmv.pdf), one can assign a name to each specification as follows:

```
LTLSPEC   NAME name := ltl_expr     [;]
CTLSPEC   NAME name := (rt)ctl_expr [;]
INVARSPEC NAME name := next_expr    [;]
PSLSPEC   NAME name := psl_expr     [;]
SPEC      NAME name := (rt)ctl_expr [;]
```

where `NAME` is a keyword and `name` is the designed *label* for the given specification.